# Find if a given functional dependency is implied from a set of functional dependencies

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

For : A→BC,CD→E,E→C,D→AEH,ABH→BD,DH→BC

Check : BCD→H

I am not understanding which axiom rule should I apply here to check. Do anyone know how to solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a functional dependency is in a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683006/checking-if-a-functional-dependency-is-in-a-closure)

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of checking if the dependency `BCD -> H` holds: the first one is by applying the [Armstrong’s axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armstrong%27s_axioms) and see if we can prove the validity of the dependency. The second one is by computing the closure of the determinant (`BCD`), and see if it contains the determinate (`H`). Consult any good book on databases to see way these two methods are equivalent.

Let’s try the first method.

```
1. D -> AEH (given)
2. D -> H (applying the decomposition rule to 1)
3. BCD -> D (applying the reflexivity rule)
4. BCD -> H (by transitivity rule on 3 and 2)
```

Let’s try the second method.

```
1. BCD+ = BCD
2. BCD+ = BCDAEH (using the dependency D -> AEH)
```

So `H` is contained in `BCD+` and so `BCD -> H` holds.